# In openLDAP, the user's initial login does not enforce password change

Tags: openldap

I am currently configuring the password policy in openLDAP with the following environment:

> OS: Ubuntu 20.04
> openLDAP 2.4.49

**ppolicy-default.ldif**

```
dn: cn=default,ou=pwPolicies,dc=my-ldap,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicyChecker
cn: default
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdCheckQuality: 2
pwdExpireWarning: 14
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdInHistory: 10
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 0
pwdMaxAge: 31536000
pwdMaxFailure: 5
pwdMinAge: 0
pwdMinLength: 12
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

**user.ldif**

```
dn: uid=someone,ou=people,dc=my-ldap,dc=com
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
uid: someone
cn: Administrator User
sn: User
userPassword: {SSHA} encrypted_password
pwdPolicySubentry: cn=default,ou=pwPolicies,dc=my-ldap,dc=com
pwdReset: TRUE
```

The password policy seems to be working, as the error occurred when trying to set the password change for user 'someone' to less than 12 characters.

> root@ldap:~# ldappasswd -H ldapi:/// -x -D uid=someone,ou=people,dc=my-ldap,dc=com -W -A -S
> Old password:
> Re-enter old password:
> New password:
> Re-enter new password:
> Enter LDAP Password:
> Result: Constraint violation (19)
> Additional info: Password fails quality checking policy

Of course, I have also tested that password changes work correctly when removing the password policy.

However, even though **pwdMustChange: TRUE** in the password policy, and **pwdReset: TRUE** for the user, the password reset procedure is not working during the initial login.

> root# **ldapwhoami -H ldapi:/// -D uid=someone,ou=people,dc=my-ldap,dc=com -W**
> Enter LDAP Password:
> dn:uid=someone,ou=people,dc=my-ldap,dc=com
> root#

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try asking in ServerFault.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: You need to use the extended password response control.

Comment: @ewokx Wow, I just discovered a website called "serverfault." Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @user207421 I was able to solve it by finding hints from your comment. Thank you for the response.

The key point is the -e option.

ldapwhoami -H ldapi:/// -x -D uid=someone,ou=people,dc=my-ldap,dc=com -e ppolicy -W